# EXISTS Syntax in sql?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, exists

I have two tables:

```
students(id, name, school_id)

schools(id, name)
```

I'm trying to use `EXISTS` in order to learn if there are any students that go to specific school, say "Harvard" for example. I know that `EXISTS` is used after `WHERE` but I'm wondering if I can do this:

```
SELECT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
    FROM students st, schools sch
    WHERE st.school_id=sch.id AND sch.name="Harvard");
```

Is this query correct? I am working on MySQL Workbench and I don't get an error. But I don't know if it does what it's supposed to do.

If it's not, then what should I change? I just want to know if it's correct and if I can use this syntax in the future.

Note that the desired result is either `yes` or `no` (`1` or `0`).

How do I get this result?

Sorry if my question was unclear, I can edit it again if you still don't understand.

Comment: What would you expect your query to return?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: BTW. Next time when you're wondering if you can do this, you better do this first and see the result for yourself.

Comment: `does this syntax work` questions can be answered through the complex mechanism of `trying it`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the count, then you would know if any exist - and if so, how many...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM students st, schools sch 
WHERE st.school_id=sch.id AND sch.name="Harvard"
```

The `EXISTS` keyword is normally used as a pre-condition... i.e. "if not exists, then add this..."

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `Select` with a `Join`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Students S
JOIN Schools SC
ON S.School_id = SC.id
Where SC.Name = 'Harvard'
```

This will give you all the rows for the students that go to Harvard, if any.  If you want to do a count you can do `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead or limit which columns are returned by indicating the specific columns in the `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 0):

This will give you student names that go to Harvard. If you wish to see how many students learn at Harvard replace `st.name` with `count(*)`.

Note that it doesn't matter what you put in `SELECT` list inside `EXISTS` statement, so choosing a constant value provides better performance than selecting columns.

```
SELECT
 st.name
FROM
 students st
WHERE
 EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM schools s WHERE s.name= 'Harvard' AND s.id = st.school_id)
```

OR

```
SELECT
 st.name
FROM
 students st
 INNER JOIN schools s ON
  st.school_id = s.id
WHERE
 s.name = 'Harvard'
```

Additional note: Code below would only yield result either `true` or `false`.

```
SELECT EXISTS ( <query> )
```

This means that below query would return true if there are any students that learn at Harvard.

```
SELECT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1 
  FROM students st 
  INNER JOIN schools s ON st.school_id = s.id 
  WHERE s.name = 'Harvard' )
```